# Exceeding recursion limit

Tags: python, recursive-query

I am new to this, and unsure why this is not working. I have looked for similar problems, but it doesn't seem to help me. The equation is `Sn=-7*Sn-1-1*Sn-2`, with initial values `S0=0` and `S1=1`

```
def s_recursive(n):
    if n==0:
        a=0
        return a
    elif n==1:
        a=1
        return a
    else:
        a=(s_recursive(-7*(n-1))-s_recursive(-1*(n-2)))
        return a
```

Comment: Can you show us some errors / traceback ?

Comment: Looks like you put in a double negative there; `-1*Sn-2` is not the same as `-s_recursive(-1*(n-2))`..

Comment: The recursive call is wrong. `a=(s_recursive(-7*(n-1))-s_recursive(-1*(n-2)))` should be `a=(-7*s_recursive(n-1)-s_recursive(n-2))`

Comment: You never reach`0` or `1` because you keep inverting `n` with multiplication; +4 becomes -29 becomes 210; so you only are going to see **larger** `n`, not smaller.

Comment: @iFlo The error is that it exceeds the recursion limit, which is to be expected with those negative args in the recursive calls.

Comment: Eric Duminil has repaired your code, but it will still be rather slow for `n > 25` or so, due to the double recursion, but you can speed it up considerably by [memoizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). The simplest way to do that in Python 3 is to use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Comment: maybe fixed don't worry

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

You're confusing `-7*s(n-1)` with `s(-7*(n-1))` :

```
def s_recursive(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    elif n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return -7*s_recursive(n-1)-s_recursive(n-2)

print s_recursive(7)
#=> 105937
print s_recursive(8)
#=> -726103
```

## Explanation

Whatever the (positive) `n` is, the recursive parameters will decrease toward `0` and `1`, so the recursion will reach an end.

For `5` as start value, it calculates `s_recursive` for `n=`:

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
1
0
3
2
1
0
1
```

and the result is `2255`.

Note that `s_recursive(2)` is calculated 3 times. With large `n`, it would be a good idea to keep a `dict` of calculated results.

## Your code

In your code, calling `-7*(n-1)` recursively was the problem. With `n=7` as start value, it calculated `s_recursive` for `n`:

```
7
-42
301
-2100
14707
-102942
720601
-5044200
35309407
-247165842
1730160901
-12111126300
84777884107
-593445188742
4154116321201
-29078814248400
203551699738807
-1424861898171642
9974033287201501
-69818233010410500
488727631072873507
-3421093417510114542
23947653922570801801
-167633577457995612600
1173435042205969288207
...
```

Comment: OP code, with `print n` as first line inside the method, and called with `s_recursive(7)`. `n=3` was wrong in the answer. Thanks